# Jboss security with SPNEGO vs Spring Security for windows single sign on

Tags: jboss, spring-security, spnego

We currently have JBOSS EAP 5.1 and a Spring web application (Spring+JSF+Spring Web Flow) working with Spring Security.

We are looking to implement single sign-on in windows env and see that it is achievable with JBOSS + SPNEGO. If I do that, would my code be redundant with Spring Security?

Are there any additional advantages If I use spring security?

Comment: Did you succeed to achieve single sign on? If yes, would you mind sharing your solution? We would like to implement single sign on on JBoss 7.2 and then map user ldap groups to spring security roles / granted authorities.

Comment: Hi Charles, I didnt attempt to marry JBOSS Security with Spring Security. The main reason being that it kind of seems to pollute the environment and there isnt a recommended way of marrying it. Keep in mind that this is about security. So.. things sounding great theoretically might have unknown loopholes.. Waffle project extension to Spring worked out for me. Im not sure on why Spring guys dropped the SPNEGO project.